# Knex data not inserting postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm

I have the following POST route to insert data into my postgres database:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
console.log('add route hit at ' + currentDate);
console.log(req.body);

knex('users').insert(
    {first_name: req.body.first_name},
    {last_name: req.body.last_name}
)
});
```

For some reason, this does not insert data into my database, but does not return any errors either. Can someone help?

Thank you!!

Comment: have you tried knex('users').insert(
    {first_name: req.body.first_name, last_name: req.body.last_name}
)

Comment: Hi - yes, but that's not working either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `then` on the knex chain

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
  return knex('users')
    .insert(req.body)
    .then(function () {
      res.send('welcome') // or something
    })
})
```